# What is the most efficient way to match keys from a dictionary to data in text file

Tags: python, text, dictionary, pandas

Say I have the following dictionary:

```
data=[a 1 : A, b 2 : B, c 3 : C, d 4 : D]
```

and a .txt file which reads:

```
Key      a 1  b 2  c 3  d 4
Word     as   box  cow  dig
```

(**note values are seperated by \t TAB character**)

How can I use the keys from the data dictionary to find the corresponding word from the .txt file? Ideally I would like to output a dictionary like:

```
data=[a 1 : as, b 2 : box, c 3 : cow, d 4 : dig]
```

Please ask for more info. if needed.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: If downvoting, please leave a comment so I can edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with open('abc') as f:
    keys = map(str.strip, next(f).split('Key      ')[1].split('  '))
    vals = map(str.strip, next(f).split('Word     ')[1].split('\t'))
    print dict(zip(keys,vals))
...     
{'d 4': 'dig', 'b 2': 'box', 'a 1': 'as', 'c 3': 'cow'}
```

Comment: Awesome, great solution, thanks! Can I ask why the [1] though?

Comment: @user1083734 `split('Key      ')` splits the  string in two parts, as we need the right part so used `[1`], i.e get the item on index 1.

Comment: I have a query, if there was a line(s) above the Key/Word line(s), what would you do to check that the correct word starts the line before assigning the variables?

Comment: @user1083734 `if line.startswith('Key'):#do something`

Comment: Fantastic, I have created another question for this plus more if you are interested in answering: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489228/reading-data-from-specially-formatted-text-file)