# Reading data from specially formatted text file

Tags: python, exception, text-files

I am using this method, kindly suggested by Ashwini Chaudhary, to assign data to a dictionary from a text file that is in a specific format.

```
keys = map(str.strip, next(f).split('Key\t')[1].split('\t'))
words = map(str.strip, next(f).split('Word\t')[1].split('\t'))
```

The text file has the row title followed by values, separated by a `\t` character.

Example 1:

```
Key      a 1  b 2  c 3  d 4
Word     as   box  cow  dig
```

How would I change my code not to read all the lines in a file, but only specific ones? Extra Lines which I do not want to read should just be ignored:

Example 2 - ignore `LineHere` and `OrHere` rows:

```
LineHere  w    x    y    z
Key       a 1  b 2  c 3  d 4
OrHere    00   01   10   11
Word      as   box  cow  dig
```

Or if I wanted to have the possibility of reading a line titled 'Word' XOR 'Letter', whichever one happens to be in the file. So the code to scan Examples 1 or 2 would also be valid for:

Example 3 - I want to read `Key` and `Letter` lines:

```
LineHere  w    x    y    z
Key       a 1  b 2  c 3  d 4
OrHere    00   01   10   11
Letter    A    B    C    D
```

Please feel free to comment with question criticisms and I'll be happy to rephrase/clarify the question.

As a reference, the precursor [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431108/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-match-keys-from-a-dictionary-to-data-in-text-f) is linked here

Many thanks,

Alex

Comment: Please specify, what is **f**. I think it's a file object. It's also not clear what particular exceptions do you mean ('What would I do to handle the following exceptions')?

Comment: @sergzach I have now edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Why do you call 'Extra Lines which you do not want to read' an 'exception'? Do you mean: "How to change my code not to read all the lines in a file, but only specific ones?"?

Comment: The data on a line 'Key' are separated with blanks, and the data on a line 'Word' are separated with tabs ?

Comment: @sergzach Yes, that is what I mean. I have updated the question

Comment: @eyquem Apologies, both are seperated by tabs. Have updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import re
with open('abc') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Key'):
            keys = re.search(r'Key\s+(.*)',line).group(1).split("\t")
        elif line.startswith(('Word','Letter')):
            vals = re.search(r'(Word|Letter)\s+(.*)',line).group(2).split("\t")

    print dict(zip(keys,vals))
```

**abc**:

```
LineHere  w    x    y    z
Key       a 1  b 2  c 3  d 4
OrHere    00   01   10   11
Word      as   box  cow  dig
```

output is :

```
{'d 4': 'dig', 'b 2': 'box', 'a 1': 'as', 'c 3': 'cow'}
```

**abc**:

```
LineHere  w    x    y    z
Key       a 1  b 2  c 3  d 4
OrHere    00   01   10   11
Letter    A    B    C    D
```

output is :

```
{'d 4': 'D', 'b 2': 'B', 'a 1': 'A', 'c 3': 'C'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ss = '''LineHere  w    x    y    z
Key       a 1  b 2  c 3  d 4
OrHere    00   01   10   11
Word      as   box  cow  dig
'''
import re

rgx = re.compile('Key +(.*)\r?\n'
                 '(?:.*\r?\n)?'
                 '(?:Word|Letter) +(.*)\r?\n')

mat = rgx.search(ss)
keys = mat.group(1).split(' ')
words = mat.group(2).split('\t')
```

You'll obtain **ss** by reading your file:

```
with open (filename) as f:
    ss = f.read()
```

#### Edit

Well, if all the lines have data separated with tabs, you can do:

```
ss = '''LineHere  w\tx\ty\tz
Key       a 1\tb 2\tc 3\td 4
OrHere    00\t01\t10\t11
Word      as\tbox\tcow\tdig
'''
import re

rgx = re.compile('Key +(.*)\r?\n'
                 '(?:.*\r?\n)?'
                 '(?:Word|Letter) +(.*)\r?\n')

print  dict(zip(*map(lambda x: x.split('\t'),
                     rgx.search(ss).groups())))
```