# Easy parsing in Python

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

I know my question might be dumb, but I'm a beginner in python and I wanted to know how I could manage to parse a little string like this :

`2 - 3`

I just want to get the two numbers and store them into two var. Is there a sscanf equivalent in python ?

Thanks

Comment: try looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489228/reading-data-from-specially-formatted-text-file

Comment: you could just think loudly in google search bar ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> s = '2 - 3'
>>> two, three = s.split(' - ')
>>> two
'2'
>>> three
'3'
```

Pretty simple way to achieve this using [tuple assignment](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html#tuple-assignment) and the built in string method [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: Maybe somebody could explain downvotes... This solution is EXACTLY what @Nicolas Charvoz asked for. And other answers are correct as well.

Comment: My guess is for providing an answer to a low quality question. I tried looking for a dupe but I couldn't find a simple/clear enough example

Answer (score 0):

You have many solutions for this problem. The most flexible and complete is to use the [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module of python.

The most simple and that works in this case is:

```
string = '2 - 3'
numbers= [int(x) for x in string.split('-')]
numbers[0]==2
numbers[1]==3
```